# How to know where to assign regions data in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-regions

I have a query regarding regions in drupal 7 . This is the code of page.tpl.php file inside my theme  . I have declared these regions in leadsnow.info file inside my theme folder. But couldn't get any idea how to use them . Like if i want to keep a piece of html tags inside  a region , yhen how would i do that . Do I need to create any file and place those divs in some file , if so then kindly guide me on this . I am new to drupal , and want to create a drupal theme from a custom raw  html file . Please help.

```
//======page.tpl.php==========
<?php if ($page['header']): ?>    
  <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

  <?php  print render($page['content']);

  <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research and development work , i came to this point . We generally declare regions to be used in out page.tpl.php page . Now after that if we want to show any data ,  on any region we have to do that through some block , for  that we have to create a block from admin pannel and assign some region to it . Then we can create a .tpl file for that block of that region and fetch data and show it . I guess , this  is the way it is done in Drupal .

Answer (score 1):

In Page.tpl.php you can only wrap your region in custom HTML as required.
Like

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
<?php if ($page['header']): ?>    
  <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

If you want to add HTML in your regions then you have to create another template file.

Read about theme hook suggestions here
https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656
and you will be more clear regarding working of templates.

Thanks.

Comment: OK , if that so , then the  code print render($page['header']) , is printing some html data , so this data is stored where , kindly guide @Mohit Madhwa

Comment: Yes, it is printing HTML data, this data is stored / written in template files responsible for that. Location of template file is dependent on theme used,
like
for sub theme = sites/all/themes/sub_theme/templates/responsible_file.tpl.php

Comment: I am not creating sub theme , it is  just a theme and my theme  folder  contains following files/folder =>css(folder),js(folder),fonts(folder),images(folder),leadsnow.info,page.tpl.php . I don't have any other files or folders. Now please help me , for regions used in  page.tpl.php  , where those .tpl file shouldbe  created and by what name . Lets say for  header region , what should i do @Mohit Wadhwa